# Ports required for SDL Web 8 on CD

Tags: web8, infrastructure

We are in the process of upgrading from SDL Tridion 2013SP1 to SDL Web8. Since Web8 is based on micro-services on the CD side, what ports are required for publishing and other tasks? I know the following services have to be installed on the presentation side and need to be accessible from the CM.

1. Discovery Service
2. Content Service
3. Deployer Service

Is there any other communication between the CM and CD environments that would need to be allowed through the firewall?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is - *"that depends on what ports you install them on."*

But if you are installing these  with default Powershell scripts you have ports 8080-8088 (I am not sure if anything uses 8086).

- Monitoring - 8080
- Content Service - 8081
- Discovery - 8082
- Preview - 8083
- Deployer - 8084
- UGC - 8085
- Context - 8087
- CID - 8088

Take a look at each PowerShell script with notepad and you will see which port each one will be installed on.

However, you might consider securing these with HTTPS, which can be a little tricky (but documented). I found the eaiest way to do this is making a [Reverse Proxy](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-42810D49-F818-4A0F-BBF5-F74EEA515438&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DHTTPS&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1469717004326&currentQuery=HTTPS&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-42810D49-F818-4A0F-BBF5-F74EEA515438&query=HTTPS&scope=&filename=GUID-42810D49-F818-4A0F-BBF5-F74EEA515438.xml&inner_id=&tid=734d3dd1-ff74-45a3-97bb-5ab60874ae55&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false) which runs on default HTTPS (port 443), and rewrites the requests to http://localhost:PORT. This way you only need one standard port open.

Additionally, you probably only need access to Discovery, Preview and Deployer from your CM machine.

Comment: CM Machine also communicates with Preview Service (for XPM Session Preview)

Comment: Interesting Rick. Thanks for the clarification. I always thought that was 100% client side. I updated the answer. Doesn't Session normally run on the same port as Content?

Comment: In addition, Audience Manager uses ports 8091 (for API) and 8092 (sync endpoint) -- and Experience Optimization uses ports 8093 (management) and 8094 (query)

Comment: That's a very long list of ports. Are all of these really required from CM to CD for full functioning assuming all modules are installed?

Comment: Hi; All these ports listed above should be opened uni-directional or bi-directional, any idea ?. Infra team asking the same who opens the port.